# How to get Details of all Department(dept_id, name, dept_manager and total_employees) from tables(Department, Employee)?

Tags: sql, oracle

Here are the details of the tables:

**Employee :**

```
   emp_ID | Primary Key
   emp_name | Varchar
   emp_email | varchar <br>
   emp_dept_id | Foreign Key
```

**Departments :**

```
   dept_ID | Primary Key 
   dept_name | Varchar 
   emp_id | Foreign Key
```

Manager details are already there in the `employee` table.
I am using `Oracle Database`.
Employee:

```
 emp_ID emp_name  emp_email    emp_dept_id
    1      Cyrus     abc@xyz.com  10
    2      Andrew    xyz@abc.com  20
    3      Mark      xyz@abc.com  10
    4      Tony      xyz@abc.com  10
    5      Elvis     xyz@abc.com  20
    6      Rock      xyz@abc.com  10
    7      George    xyz@abc.com  20
    8      Mary      xyz@abc.com  10
    9      Thomas    xyz@abc.com  20
    10      Martin   xyz@abc.com  10
```

Depqartments:

```
dept_id     dept_name     emp_id
    10       Accounts     4
    20       Development  9
```

These are the data in the tables. In Department table, emp_id(Foreign key) indicates the head/manager of the department .

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. Also take a look at [mcve].

Comment: wait i'll update it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following query:

```
SELECT
    D.DEPT_ID,
    D.DEPT_NAME,
    D.EMP_ID      AS MANAGER_ID,
    E.EMP_NAME    AS MANAGER_NAME,
    E.EMP_EMAIL   AS MANAGER_EMAIL,
    E.CNT         AS "number of employees"
FROM
    DEPARTMENT D
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            EMP_ID,
            EMP_NAME,
            EMP_EMAIL,
            EMP_DEPT_ID,
            COUNT(1) OVER(
                PARTITION BY EMP_DEPT_ID
            ) AS CNT
        FROM
            EMPLOYEE
    ) E ON ( E.DEPT_ID = D.EMP_DEPT_ID
             AND E.EMP_ID = D.EMP_ID );
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straightforward.  You want to get the department details (1) and also include the employees associated with that department (2).

1. Get the department details:

```sql
    SELECT <dept_col1>, <dept_col2>, ...
    FROM Department
```

2. Get a summary of employees per department:

```sql
SELECT dept_ID, <aggregation> AS MyAgg
FROM department
GROUP BY dept_ID
```

Here you replace `<aggregation>` with whatever you're trying to find.  In your case it would be `COUNT(*)`.

3. Combine the two results.  You want to join the data from (2) to (1).  How are these two tables related?  Here you write a `LEFT JOIN` to connect them on the PK/FK relationship:

```sql
    SELECT 
      dept.<col1>, dept.<col2>, ..., 
      COALESCE(emp.MyAgg,0) AS MyAgg
    FROM Department dept
    LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT dept_ID, <aggregation> AS MyAgg
      FROM department
      GROUP BY dept_ID
    ) emp ON dept.<FK> = emp.<PK>
```

4. Get the department manager's info by adding another `LEFT JOIN`:

```sql
    SELECT 
      dept.<col1>, dept.<col2>, ..., 
      mgr.<col1>, 
      COALESCE(emp.MyAgg,0) AS MyAgg -- In case there are 0 employees
    FROM Department dept
    LEFT JOIN employee mgr ON dept.<FK> = mgr.<PK>
    LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT dept_ID, <aggregation> AS MyAgg
      FROM department
      GROUP BY dept_ID
    ) emp ON dept.<FK> = emp.<PK>
```

Give it a try and see how far you get.  If you get stuck let me know.

Comment: I am having details of all employees in the employee table and the department details in department table. 'emp_id'(this column indicates the manager of the department) in the department table is referencing 'emp_id' in the employee table.

Comment: I want a query which will give details of all departments i.e dept_id, dept_name, dept_manager(here it will be referencing to emp_id field of employee) and the total number of employees.

Comment: OK, I see.  I added another step to help you get the department manager's info as well.  There are simpler ways to do it, but hopefully this gives an idea of where to get the data from and how to manipulate it.